# how to set window.width via javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making my site to be responsive, however, I have a small problem. When I scroll down after 550px the classic logo is removed and the minified is showing up. The problem is with mobile version, when I scroll down and then return up the classic logo is there. How can I set if window.width < 375 this script not to run? Any other solution?

```
   window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };
    
    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 550 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 550 && window.width > 375 ) {
            document.getElementById("header").style.height = "80px";
            document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "block";
    
        } else {
            document.getElementById("header").style.height = "100px";
            document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Comment: [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

Comment: "*How can I set if window.width < 375 this script not to run?*" ... why not just add an `if` at the top of the function that `return`s if this condition is met...? It sounds to me like you already have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ((document.body.scrollTop > 550 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 550) && window.innerWidth > 375) {
// ... your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your function to below

```
function scrollFunction() {
        if ((document.body.scrollTop > 550 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 550) && window.innerWidth > 375 ) {
            document.getElementById("header").style.height = "80px";
            document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "block";
    
        } else {
            document.getElementById("header").style.height = "100px";
            document.getElementById('minifyed-logo').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('classic-logo').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```